# Make Traefik return errors in JSON format

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to configure errors from Traefik to be returned in JSON format, but in the [docs for configuring custom error pages](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/commons/#custom-error-pages) no such simple option seems to be available.

So instead of returning a 503 with

```
Service Unavailable
```

when the backend is down, I'd just simply would like to return valid JSON with the same message. Maybe something like

```
{"statusCode": 503, "message": "Service Unavailable"}
```

From the docs I understand that a custom error page is fetched from the backend itself, but if the backend is down it would be impossible.

What is the easiest way to make all Traefik responses be returned in JSON format?